# Flutter Firebase GetX App automatic navigation to the homepage

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-getx

Everytime i get this in my console:
`

```
W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 5199): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
D/FirebaseAuth( 5199): Notifying id token listeners about user ( vf7HKywcZTU... ).
```

My Flutter App auto navigates to the Homepage.
I am using GetX for navigation and using Firebase for Authentication.
This happens after a period of time when the app is either in use or just not in use but opened.

Then after going to the homepage, it displays this message:

```
I/companyname.appname( 5199): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 665534(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(6032KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 127MB/150MB, paused 11.945ms total 335.119ms
W/companyname.appname( 5199): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 135 to 100
```

This is my Auth Controller class.
`

```
class Auth extends GetXController{
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();
  final StudentController student = Get.put(StudentController());
  late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());

    ever(_user, _initialScreen);
  }

  _initialScreen(User? user) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final finishedOnboarding = prefs.getBool('finishedOnboarding') ?? false;
    if (finishedOnboarding) {
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
        Get.offAll(() => const HomeScreen());
      } else {
        Get.offAll(() => const LoginView());
      }
    } else {
      Get.offAll(const OnboardingView());
    }
  }
}
```

Where could I be going wrong?
I am suspecting a network issue, maybe the navigation? or maybe incopatibility issues?
My dependencies are:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  get: ^4.6.6
```

I have tried changing my navigation logic to use the default Flutter `Navigator.of(context).push` as I only relied on GetX to handle Navigation. eg: `Get.to(()=>SomePage());`